# CakePHP 2.0 not returning 403

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I was creating an AJAX based application in cakePHP 1.3, and I decided to move to CakePHP 2.0. Now restricted actions called by ajax no longer return a 403 error when not logged in. I used this to alert my user that he needs to re-log in. How can I make sure CakePHP returns a 403 when not logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake 2.0 has a [built-in exception class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) for 403s.

> *exception* **ForbiddenException**
>      Used for doing a 403 Forbidden error.

Use it like such:

```
function view() {
    if ( !MyLoginVerificationFunction() ) {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this on a global level such as in the AppController?

Comment: @LordZ Yup, do it in the BeforeFilter of your AppController.

Comment: Ok, one last thing, can you show me what "MyLoginVerficationFunction" would look like?

Comment: @LordZ that was meant as a placeholder for whatever method you are using to determine authentication.

Comment: I don't think i'm doing anything to determine authenticaion l. I thought the auth component did all that for me.

Comment: @LordZ But you still have to check the Auth component to see if the user is logged in.  So replace the placeholder pseudocode function with your function that checks `Auth::user` ...

Comment: Is there an article that explains this in detail so i can get an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: @LordZardeck Open another question.  This question was about how to deliver a 403 error from CakePHP 2.0